# Setting background of layout in Xamarin Android - overriding Dark Mode

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to set background to my Android app.

But setting it with `android:background` property does not work:

```
<GridLayout ...
    android:background="#ffffff00">
```

I even set the background on parent element:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff00">
```

But it still shows me just dark background.

I have dark mode truned on on my mobile (Xiaomi if that matters). When I switch this mode off, backgrounds work as expected.

So I would like to know how to override dark mode in a app?

It looks like that this dark mode overrides already this property and it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on answer of @Colex-MSFT I got it resolved:

he was right with suggestion that I should put

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
```

in `res/values/styles.xml)`. Then I inspected it once again and out that project is autmatically created with following section in the file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
         Customize your theme here. 
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

(those colors are just defined in `colors.xml` file) so, I just commented out this (maybe will delete) and just left suggested line and it works - dark mode is no more forced in my application :)

Answer (score 1):

How did you make your app support dark mode ?

I followed the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme) ,just set the app's theme (usually found in `res/values/styles.xml`) to inherit from a `DayNight` theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
```

##### Light mode

[image]

##### Dark mode

[image]

Same code works as expected on my side .(The yellow part is GridLayout)

---

**Suggestion** :

1. Test in a blank project .
2. Test on another device .

Comment: Actually i did not do nothing to support dark mode in app.

Comment: Can you try this on simulator or  another device ?